# Getting error while deleting a document in couchdb using node-couchdb-api

Tags: node.js, couchdb

```
var couchdb = require("couchdb-api");
var server = couchdb.srv(localhost, 5984, false, false);
var db = server.db("test");
var doc = db.doc("d5e1d042d579fcb1b3d4df07bc001f74");
doc.del(function (err, response) {
console.log(response);
console.log(err);
});
```

after that i am facing the problem,

```
null
{ error: 'bad_request', reason: 'Invalid rev format' }
```

but the corresponding document having the proper revision like 1-135dc47e3492a980fa45b3af9eb22a97 and proper data.

Please provide me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of this module. The issue here is that you are attempting to delete the document without a revision number. (there is a `_rev` number on your document, but `couchdb-api` does not have that information) Any other attempt to write would also trigger this error under these conditions.

You have a couple options as it stands now:

**Get the current document before attempting to write/delete**

```
doc.get(function (err, body) {
    doc.del(function (err, results) {
        // the delete will be successful
    });
});
```

**Explicitly set your revision number before attempting the write/delete**

```
doc.body._rev = "1-myrevisionnumber";
doc.del(...);
```

I'm going to add a better error message here, and I'm considering adding a special flag that will tell `couchdb-api` to "force" a delete even if it doesn't have the latest revision number. (ie. it will call `get` before `del` in order to avoid MVCC)

Comment: +1. Dominic, if you ever add that feature, look into Txn which would bring you most of the way there (with extra features such as auto-retry on conflicts) https://github.com/iriscouch/txn